# Checksum() for minus

Tags: sql, t-sql

Why does **checksum()** function return **0** for the minus?

```
select checksum('-')   /* 0 */
select checksum('---') /* 0 */
select checksum('-+-') /* 67 */
select checksum('+')   /* 67 */
```

Comment: From msdn: [CHECKSUM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms189788.aspx) `is intended for use in building hash indexes.`

Comment: Which database engine are you using ? with sql-server I got respectively the following : 45, 12285, 12189, 43

Comment: Why does that surprise you? It's a hash code and apparently a bad one. I can give you infinitely many inputs that also return zero.

Comment: This has to do with how `CHECKSUM` calculates over `(N)CHAR` values with particular collations; apparently the net effect is as if the string had all hyphens stripped. You will not observe the same by using a binary collation (`CHECKSUM('-' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin)`). Why does this happen? Presumably only the person(s) who worked on `CHECKSUM` can tell. As has been mentioned, `CHECKSUM` is a pretty terrible hash. `BINARY_CHECKSUM` is marginally better, `HASHBYTES` is a lot better.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think this is because CHECKSUM obeys the exact same rules that string equality observes under a given collation. You should post an answer.

Comment: @usr: nope. `'a' != '---a---' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI`, but `CHECKSUM('a' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI) == CHECKSUM('---a---' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI)`. You're right that you would expect the checksums to be equal if the strings compare equal, but that's not what's happening here.

Comment: @JeroenMostert disappointing. Here's the algorithm btw: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=70832. Minus chars do not seem to be ignored. The OPs examples just happen to suggest that.; The algorithm is a bad tradeoff of CPU usage and hash quality. That guy did not know what he was doing.

Comment: @usr: that's the reverse-engineered code for `BINARY_CHECKSUM`, which has no trouble keeping its hyphens in order. `CHECKSUM` is really doing something weird here, that just happens to reduce the contribution of every hyphen character to the checksum to 0 under certain collations. I'm not suggesting it's removing hyphens, but the algorithm just happens to end up *as if* all hyphens were removed prior to hashing. I'm not really qualified to answer the question beyond "this is how `CHECKSUM` happens to work and if that's a problem for you, don't use `CHECKSUM`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wikipedia, Hash Functions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function):

> A hash function is any function that can be used to map digital data of arbitrary size to digital data of fixed size. The values returned by a hash function are called hash values, hash codes, hash sums, or simply hashes.

Under this definition, you could have a function that returns a zero for any input, but it would be the worst possible hash. So, if you are asking why they didn't choose a better algorithm, I'm not sure you are asking the right people. You may want to ask Microsoft. We can infer by a comment made on MSDN that at least someone at Microsoft is aware that CHECKSUM is not the ideal hash function. Here, they recommend HASHBYTES if you need a particularly good hash.

From MSDN, CHECKSUM(Transact-SQL): (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx)

> CHECKSUM satisfies the properties of a hash function: CHECKSUM applied over any two lists of expressions returns the same value if the corresponding elements of the two lists have the same type and are equal when compared using the equals (=) operator. For this definition, null values of a specified type are considered to compare as equal. If one of the values in the expression list changes, the CHECKSUM of the list also generally changes. However, there is a small chance that the CHECKSUM will not change. For this reason, we do not recommend using CHECKSUM to detect whether values have changed, unless your application can tolerate occasionally missing a change. Consider using HashBytes instead. When an MD5 hash algorithm is specified, the probability of HashBytes returning the same result for two different inputs is much lower than that of CHECKSUM.